# Elasticsearch search does not return exact results

Tags: elasticsearch, couchdb, nosql

I was trying to run elasticsearch on couchdb using river plugin. Unfortunately, the number of hits i have got is the same with the total of actual documents. Say that i have 10000 documents in my couch database, however, it only returns 9340 hits in elasticsearch. Anyone knows why this problem arise? Would you mind to explain it to me please?

Regards,

Jemie Effendy

Comment: Could you please post the error in elasticsearch.log? Also is it goin to stop at exact count when u run each time?

Comment: Typically you should post your mapping and the query itself, allows people to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [bool query.](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/query-dsl-bool-query.html) This will return results that `MUST` have what you've defined in your query. Also look into your mapping, Elasticsearch may be tokenising your data in a way in which you don't expect.